# WinAPI, TreeView: a gray item by TVIS_CUT

Tags: c, winapi, treeview

I want to make a item gray. According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-item-states) I set `TVIS_CUT` in `stateMask` and `mask`.
But it doesn't work (the item is black as usual). `TVIS_BOLD` works perfect.

I use CodeBlocks17 (gcc)/Win7x64. Also I tried VS2005 and another OS (WinXP) with the same result.
What did I miss?

```
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK cbMain (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow) {
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc{0};

    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyAppClass");
    wc.lpfnWndProc = cbMain;
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDC_ICON);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wc))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    HWND hMainWnd = CreateWindowEx (0, TEXT("MyAppClass"), NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 500, 600, 160, 300, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hTreeWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT  | TVS_EDITLABELS, 0, 0, 150, 200, hMainWnd, (HMENU)100, hInstance,  NULL);

    TVITEM tvi{0};
    tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_STATE;
    tvi.pszText = TEXT("Item");
    tvi.cchTextMax = 40;
    tvi.stateMask = TVIS_CUT;
    tvi.state = TVIS_CUT;

    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins{0};
    tvins.item = tvi;
    tvins.hInsertAfter = TVI_ROOT;
    tvins.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
    SendMessage(hTreeWnd, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK cbMain (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `TVIS_CUT` will ghost (fade) the icon but it won't change the text color. You need to use [Custom Draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-custom-draw) for that.

Comment: The following code example sets a tree-view item to disabled state: [`m_treeCtrl.SetItemStateEx(hPA, TVIS_EX_DISABLED);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class?view=msvc-160#example-69) You can check if it helps.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, thanks. I checked it and yes, with icons it works. But I don't use icons.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT, it's a MFC way. Pure WinAPI doesn't have this method and `TVIS_EX_DISABLED` constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Custom Draw` as Jonathan Potter said.

Here is one pitfall: while a current item changing, old item has `CDIS_FOCUS` and `CDIS_SELECTED` flags in `pCustomDraw->nmcd.uItemState` member, and new item doesn't have. So `pCustomDraw->clrText = (pNMTVCD->nmcd.uItemState & CDIS_FOCUS) == CDIS_FOCUS) ? ...` will works a little bit strange. I checked `pCustomDraw->clrTextBk` instead. But it can be broken when user used a custom theme.

I use [this article](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/248496) and an applied [code](http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sampleA/2000/WIN98/EN-US/custdtv.exe) to build the example.

```
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#define IDC_TREEVIEW 100

LRESULT CALLBACK cbMain (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow) {
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc{0};

    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyAppClass");
    wc.lpfnWndProc = cbMain;
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDC_ICON);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wc))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    HWND hMainWnd = CreateWindowEx (0, TEXT("MyAppClass"), NULL, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU, 500, 600, 160, 300, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    HWND hTreeWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT  | TVS_EDITLABELS, 0, 0, 150, 200, hMainWnd, (HMENU)IDC_TREEVIEW, hInstance,  NULL);

    TVITEM tvi{0};
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins{0};
    tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_STATE;
    tvi.pszText = TEXT("Item1");
    tvi.cchTextMax = 40;
    tvi.stateMask = 0;
    tvi.state = 0;

    tvins.item = tvi;
    tvins.hInsertAfter = TVI_ROOT;
    tvins.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
    SendMessage(hTreeWnd, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);

    tvi.pszText = TEXT("Item2");
    tvins.item = tvi;
    SendMessage(hTreeWnd, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);

    tvi.stateMask = TVIS_CUT;
    tvi.state = TVIS_CUT;
    tvi.pszText = TEXT("Item3");
    tvins.item = tvi;
    SendMessage(hTreeWnd, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK cbMain (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage (0);
        }
        break;

        case WM_NOTIFY: {
            NMHDR* pHdr = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
            if (pHdr->idFrom == IDC_TREEVIEW && pHdr->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {
                LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW pCustomDraw = (LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
                if (pCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage == CDDS_PREPAINT)
                    return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

                if (pCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage == CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT) {
                    BOOL isCut = TreeView_GetItemState(pHdr->hwndFrom, (HTREEITEM)pCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec, TVIS_CUT) & TVIS_CUT;
                    pCustomDraw->clrText = pCustomDraw->clrTextBk != RGB( 255, 255, 255) ? RGB( 255, 255, 255) :
                        isCut ? RGB( 128, 128, 128 ) : RGB( 0, 0, 0);
                }

                return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```